# Error when handling tagged files in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

When handling files with Finder tags I frequently get an error alert, "The operation can't be completed. An unexpected error occurred (error code -8076)." This usually happens when I have multiple tagged items selected. Sometimes it happens a few times in quick succession, with the alert popping up again as soon as it is dismissed... & again, & again, up to 5 times.

[image]

Can anyone tell me of a way to stop this happening? (apart from not using Finder tags)

Comment: The error code 8076 is a permissions error, which means that the user does not have the required permission to access or modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

I will usually get this error, if I select items in a folder and its subfolders and try to add or remove tags.

The only way I found around this is to use a different option for tagging after the error appeared. For example, instead of changing tags in the preview pane on the right, use *Edit Tags* in the toolbar or *Tags...* in the context menu, use a shortcut like CTRL-0, drop the files onto a tag in the sidebar on the left or change the selected files.

Ultimately, I've built an app, that helps me with some of these issues when manually tagging files.

Comment: I always add & remove tags using the contextual menu. It's when selecting & performing operations on tagged items that I get this error.